# How to find all QName references to an element with ID

Tags: xpath, msxml

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:definitions xmlns:ns="http://just.a.test">
    <ns:item id="_abc" value="foo"/>
    <ns:ref itemId='ns:_abc' text='ref1'/>
    <ns:ref itemId='_abc' text='ref2'/>
</ns:definitions>
```

In the schema, `itemId` is declared as `QName`, i.e. it may contain a prefixed or unprefoxed name.

I now want to find all references to the item with id '_abc', using XPath 1.0 (using MSXML, to be precise).

`//ns:ref[@itemId='ns:_abc']` will only find the first reference (ref1).
`//ns:ref[@itemId='_abc']` will only find the second reference (ref2).

Is there a shorter way than `//ns:ref[@itemId='_abc' or @itemId='ns:_abc']` to find all references to `<ns:item id='_abc' ... />`, regardless whether they are qualified or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `//ns:ref[@itemId = '_abc' or substring-after(@itemId, ':') = '_abc']` then I think your verbal description "to find all references, regardless whether they are qualified or not" is covered. I have some doubts however that for an `ID` value in XML the values `_abc` and `ns:_abc` would reference the same item, or even if `ID` derived from `NCName` allows any colon: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NCName.

Comment: See my edits above. itemId is a QName, not a NCName.

Comment: I think my suggestion still holds, as far as XPath 1.0 with no notion of `QName` can do that. But even if  `_abc` and `ns:_abc` are compared as QNames, I don't think they would be considered equal. At least not with the definition of QNames that XSLT/XPath 2.0 implement, see a sample http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y8P.